# Download TestFlight crash reports

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, crash-reports

From [Apple developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-crashes_organizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer.html) I had come to know how to download the TestFlight crash reports. In the crash organiser it's shows only upto build number 3 while I have uploaded 6 build to the TestFlight. Now I remembered that from build number 4 we used `Application loader` to upload the binary. Though I am not very sure if `Application loader` is the only reason.

Can anyone please let me know how to download TestFlight crash reports?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: I knew that then where should I post this?

Comment: I have no idea; probably the Apple Developer Forums.